# How do I install Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser

When searching for how to install Firefox, results show how to update it (not helpful). I assume it's because Firefox USED TO BE the default browser, but now it is not installed with my version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu 16.04). So, I would appreciate clear info on the how to INSTALL Firefox question.

Question: How do I install Firefox on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Er, what? Firefox is most certainly still the default browser for 16.04 and comes pre-installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install Firefox using Ubuntu Software Center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282706/unable-to-install-firefox-using-ubuntu-software-center) and [how to update an individual app through terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656545/how-to-update-an-individual-app-through-terminal)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install software using the Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66447/how-do-i-install-software-using-the-ubuntu-software-center)

Comment: @karel OP's not asking how to upgrade an app and there's no evidence his problem is your other link.

Comment: The reason I added the second link is that in one of the answers it said that Firefox was already installed by default and if I didn't include that link then the OP could claim that this is a unique question because I didn't include a second link to confirm it, instead of a duplicate question because I did include a second link to confirm it.

Comment: See the link https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04

Answer (score 17):

Open Terminal and run

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

Comment: Note: If anyone is getting `E: Package 'firefox' has no installation candidate` then you'll want to run `sudo apt update` first.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to install it is to click on "ubuntu software" on the desktop, then search and install from there.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A6DCF7707EBC211F
$ sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa/ubuntu bionic main"

$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install firefox
```